# Jest testing - how to handle JsonWebToken response

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk, jest-fetch-mock

I am learning how to test my redux thunk actions and the response from my login includes a randomized JsonWebToken. I've written a variable called `expectedActions` that matches all the data coming back from the action except how to handle randomized strings (JWT). Any ideas on how to handle this?

-- Also, i need to pass real user information (usename/password) to get a `LOGIN_SUCCESS` response otherwise the function dispatches the `LOGIN_FAIL` action. Is that normal?

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';
import * as actions from '../../../redux/actions/auth';

const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);

describe('redux async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.reset();
    fetchMock.restore();
  });

  it('returns expected login response', async () => {
    const userData = {
      username: 'user',
      email: 'user@gmail.com',
      password: 'password',
    };
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
    fetchMock.getOnce('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users', {
      body: { ...userData },
      config,
    });

    const expectedActions = { payload: { token: '' }, type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' };
    // the value of the token above in the response is a randomized jwt string

    const store = mockStore({});

    return store
      .dispatch(actions.login('user@gmail.com', 'password'))
      .then(() => {
        // return of async actions
        const actionsResponse = store.getActions();
        expect(actionsResponse[0]).toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```

**Bonus:** What is the point of `fetchMock` ? I borrowed the above code from another StackOverflow question and I have yet to understand what the fetchMock is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I overrode the responses JWT with my own token of "123". I don't know if this is correct though, nor do i ever expect a response to this post.

```
const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);

describe('redux async actions', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.reset();
    fetchMock.restore();
  });

  it('returns expected login response', async () => {
    const expectedActions = {
      payload: { token: '123' },
      type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    };

    const store = mockStore({ alert: [], auth: { token: '123' } });

    return store
      .dispatch(actions.login('user@gmail.com', 'somePassword'))
      .then(() => {
        // return of async actions
        const actionsResponse = store.getActions();
        actionsResponse[0].payload.token = '123';
        expect(actionsResponse[0]).toEqual(expectedActions);
      });
  });
});
```